# Colored table in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figure out how to generate a colored chart on a matlab, like the one you can find in [here](http://web.mit.edu/sp.268/www/risk.pdf) on page 9. (You will have to look through it to find what I am referring to - Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post pictures in the postings just yet.)

A few questions:

1. I do have the table, but my table is a set of discreet points, not a continuous spectrum. So... can I do it in the first place?
2. If it IS possible, how would I do it?

(By the way, that table is from combat simulation for [Risk](http://web.mit.edu/sp.268/www/risk.pdf) - I am doing the combat simulation for Risk II, just for fun.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of image you are looking for, as can be seen on Page 9, is a `imagesc` plot. Here's a simple example, using a double sin function. Done without vectorization for simplicity.

```
x=0:pi/180:pi;
y=0:pi/180:pi;

output=zeros(length(x),length(y));
for ix=1:length(x)
   for iy=1:length(x)
      output(ix,iy)=sin(x(ix)*2)*cos(y(iy)*4);
   end
end
figure;imagesc(x,y,output)
```

Comment: Don't think vectorization makes this more complicated: `[x,y]=meshgrid(0:pi/180:pi,0:pi/180:pi); output = sin(x*2)+cos(y*4); figure,imagesc(x(:,1),y(1,:),output);`

Comment: @Jonas: Sure, it's just too early in the morning for me to remember the meshgrid command...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the filled contourplot. 
See also: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/contourf.html

Comment: I am not exactly looking for contour plots... the plot there doesn't have any contour line either.

Comment: Then you have to be more clear what picture (page number etc) you are referring to.

Comment: `contourf` gives you exactly the kind of plot you are referring to. It is designed for plotting 2D tabular-type values. You can also disable the lines (See e.g http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/51962 ). , to remain with only colours. Please explain why your case is different?